# Can you create a multiple select list without checkboxes in InfoPath 2010?

Tags: infopath, custom-form

Is there a way to create the list box style control found at the top of the form on this page?:

http://www.sjbhealth.org/body_south.cfm?id=1290

It seems like the multi-selection list box control only allows lists with checkboxes.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to create the list box style control found at the top
>   of the form on this page?:
>
> http://www.sjbhealth.org/body_south.cfm?id=1290

Yes, Infopath **Drop-Down List Box** control does/looks exactly the same

> It seems like the multi-selection list box control only allows lists
>   with checkboxes

Yes, you are correct. Infopath **Multiple-Selection List Box** control permits selecting multiple items through rendered checkboxes only.

Seems like you refer to "control found at the top of the form on this page" as if permitting the multiple selections without checkboxes but it really permits there only single choices and is equal to Infopath **Drop-Down List Box**